# React Native programmatically swipe gesture on element

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-animatable, react-native-gesture-handler

In this fantastic video, made by William Candillon from http://start-react-native.dev he shows how to make this off-screen menu. Code can be found here: https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/the-10-min/src/Menu

My question is, would it be possible to create a function that can close the profile screen programmatically instead of the user swiping on the profile card. 
Preferably, it closes with the animation, but a plan B could be to just gracefully return the state of the animation back to the starting point. A general function that can fake a swipe would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!